# Higher-order, partial function — where to place @unchecked annotation?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, non-exhaustive-patterns

I've a piece of code for which I get a "match may not be exhaustive" warning from Scala 2.13.4, and I'd like to **suppress that warning** with the `@unchecked` annotation. Unfortunately, all my attempts of inserting `@unchecked` merely resulted in syntax errors.

Here's a mercilessly simplified version of the original code:

```scala
def foo(xs: Seq[Int], n: Int)(f: (Seq[Int], Int) => Int): Int = f(xs, n)
    
foo(Seq(1,2), 0) { case (Seq(a,b), c) => a + b + c }
```

**Question:** Where do I syntactically put `@unchecked` **at call site** in order to suppress the warning?

<sub>P.S. I'd like to suppress the warning, not start a discussion of whether or not that is evil ;-)</sub>

Comment: I am not sure that I've got it right, but I can't reproduce it: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/jujYc1IDTx20lIRZSGjPBA/3

Comment: @TomerShetah Interesting - I'll check what the project's compiler options are, maybe there's something special there. Either way, I'd still like to find out where to put `@unchecked`.

Comment: @TomerShetah Not need to reproduce the warning: if you managed to squeeze in `@unchecked` without causing compiler errors, you'd have helped me already :-)

Comment: I hope I have enough unchecked in my code to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood this correctly but have you tried something like this:

```
def pie(x: Option[String]) =
(x: @unchecked) match {
  case Some(v) => v
}
```

The warning is removed (for me) with this syntax

Comment: I also managed to get it working for this rather simple case, but failed for the more complex code shown in the question

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure what is that good for, but I think this is the maximum `unchecked` you can do in the code in the question:

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int @unchecked] @unchecked, n: Int @unchecked)(f: (Seq[Int @unchecked] @unchecked, Int @unchecked) => Int @unchecked): Int @unchecked = {
  f(xs, n)
}

println(foo(Seq(1,2), 0) {
  case (Seq(a: Int @unchecked,b: Int @unchecked), c: Int @unchecked) => a + b + c
})
```

[`unchecked` in Scaladoc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/unchecked.html). Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/LwlLj9YwQGmTfMcU6sHoIQ).

Comment: That are indeed a lot of `@unchecked` :-) These suppress checks for every use of `foo` (since they are placed at definition site), but what I'd like is to suppress is the check at call-site, where there is an implicit pattern matching — at call site — in the form of the partial function that is passed as the second argument to `foo`. I've clarified my question, and in case I find a solution myself, I'll get back to you.

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff, does I've updated my answer. Does that help you?

Comment: I see you like a challenge :-) Unfortunately, it doesn't help, probably because the annotations affect the elements of the sequence, rather than the sequence itself. I.e. they don't suppress complaints about not matching against arbitrary-sized sequences. It is obvious that debugging blindly (since you don't get the compiler warning) is not ideal. I unfortunately didn't yet manage to distil a sufficiently small example that still causes the warnings :-/

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get warnings after enabling "unchecked" in compiler options in IntelliJ. It's not scalastyle, is it?
I appreciate your example is contrived. Does either of these approaches work for you?

Option 1: Defining your curried function as a PartialFunction

```
def foo(xs: Seq[Int], n: Int) (f: PartialFunction[(Seq[Int], Int), Int]): Int = 
    if(f.isDefinedAt(xs, n))
        f(xs, n)
    else 0
```

Option 2: Converting your case statement to a match expression?

```
foo(Seq(1,2), 0) {
  (_:(Seq[Int], Int) @unchecked) match
  {
    case (Seq(a, b), c) => a + b + c
  }
}
```

Comment: Option 2 looks more like it, but it unfortunately doesn't compile: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YwMeJzDdR7ebGbINm5jtpw

Comment: @MalteSchwerhoff a combination of 1 and 2 works
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmhS8BGTSaKcgRqrpPAqkA